# What is the best way to set global filters for multiple resources on react-admin?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-admin

I try to implement an admin ui based on react-admin. Now I have multiple resources, which have the same filter criterias. What is the best way to sync the filters across all resources?

Tried to set filterDefaultValues, filters. Although tried to assign the same Filter-Component to multiple resources.

I have really no idea how to sync "YourFilter" with "MyFilter". Expected: You are on MyData, set a filter based on /apples. You switch to YourData, the filter should be pre-selected.

How to realize it?

```
// in src/mydata.js
const MyFilter = (props) => (
    <Filter {...props}>
        <ReferenceInput label="Apple" source="appleid" reference="apples" allowEmpty alwaysOn>
            <SelectInput optionText="applename" />
        </ReferenceInput>
    </Filter>
);

export const MyDataList = (props) => (
    <List {...props} title="My Data" filters={<MyFilter />}>
        <Datagrid>
        // ...
        </Datagrid>
    </List>
);
```

```
// in src/yourdata.js
const YourFilter = (props) => (
    <Filter {...props}>
        <ReferenceInput label="Apple" source="appleid" reference="apples" allowEmpty alwaysOn>
            <SelectInput optionText="applename" />
        </ReferenceInput>
    </Filter>
);

export const YourDataList = (props) => (
    <List {...props} title="Your Data" filters={<YourFilter />}>
        <Datagrid>
        // ...
        </Datagrid>
    </List>
);
```

```
// in src/App.js
const App = () => (
  <Admin dataProvider={dataProvider}>
    <Resource name="MyData" list={MyDataList} />
    <Resource name="YourData" list={YourDataList} />
  </Admin>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If `MyFilter` and `YourFilter` are strictly the same, you can use the same filter component for both.

```js
// filters.js
export const CustomFilter = (props) => (
    <Filter {...props}>
        <ReferenceInput label="Apple" source="appleid" reference="apples" allowEmpty alwaysOn>
            <SelectInput optionText="applename" />
        </ReferenceInput>
    </Filter>
);
```

```js
// ResourceA.js
import { CustomFilter } from './filters';

export const ResourceAList = (props) => (
    <List {...props} title="My Data A" filters={<CustomFilter />}>
        <Datagrid>
        // ...
        </Datagrid>
    </List>
);
```

```js
// ResourceB.js
import { CustomFilter } from './filters';

export const ResourceBList = (props) => (
    <List {...props} title="My Data B" filters={<CustomFilter />}>
        <Datagrid>
        // ...
        </Datagrid>
    </List>
);
```

```js
// in src/App.js
import { ResourceAList } from './ResourceA';
import { ResourceBList } from './ResourceB';

const App = () => (
  <Admin dataProvider={dataProvider}>
    <Resource name="MyDataA" list={ResourceAList} />
    <Resource name="MyDataB" list={ResourceBList} />
  </Admin>
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately it does not work. Both resources have the same filter options, but the state is independet. If one changes filters in ResourceA, the filters in ResourceB are not changed. Do you have any idea how to solve it?

Comment: I'm not sure the duplicated components should share the same state. Mind you fork the following CodeSandbox and reproduce the state sharing issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/n5q09v99xl